# Why does the block after dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() never get called?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I want to execute some code asynchronously and have for this reason started using GCD for OSX/iOS.
Currently I am using the function *dispatch_async()*.
When I want to execute something concurrently on another thread, I use the function *dispatch_get_global_queue()*.
When I want to dispatch the result to the main thread, I use the function *dispatch_get_main_queue()*.
But the results never arrive to the main thread.

When setting up breakpoints in the debugger (at the *dispatch_async* lines), the block after function *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)* 
gets executed only sometimes, but often the debugger just ignores it.
When the block does get executed and execution flow gets to the breakpoint at *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()*, the block after that always gets ignored.

Without *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue)* and *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)* the code executes as it should, albeit synchronously.

My question is why does *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()* inside of the *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue()* block never get executed?
And on the same note, why is the *dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue()* block not getting executed every time?

My development environment is
OS: *OS X 10.11.3*
IDE:              *Xcode 7.2*
Compiler:         *Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)*
Target:           *x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0*

Here is a simple example which reproduces the erratic behavior (an OS X console application):

*TestClass.h*

```
#ifndef TestClass_h
#define TestClass_h

@interface TestClass : NSObject {
}

- (void)testMethod:(NSString *)testString withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString *blockResult, NSError __autoreleasing *error))completionBlock;

@end

#endif
```

*TestClass.m*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass

- (void)testMethod:(NSString *)testString withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString *blockResult, NSError __autoreleasing *error))completionBlock {
    __block NSString *stringResult = nil;

    if (completionBlock) {
        __block NSError *resultError = nil;


       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // THIS BLOCK IS CALLED ONLY SOMETIMES, MOST OF THE TIME IT IS IGNORED.

            if ([testString isEqual: @"Error string"]) {
                NSDictionary *errorUserInfo = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"This is an error.", NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: @"", NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: @"" };                
                resultError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"com.test.TestErrorDomain" code:10 userInfo:errorUserInfo];
            }
            else {
                stringResult = testString;
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // THIS BLOCK NEVER GETS EXECUTED.

                completionBlock(stringResult, resultError);
            });
        });
    }
}

@end
```

*main.m*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        __block NSString *resultString = nil;
        TestClass * testObject = [[TestClass alloc] init];

        // Output for this call should be: The result string is: Test string.
        [testObject testMethod:@"Test string" withCompletionBlock:^(NSString *blockString, NSError __autoreleasing *error) {
            resultString = blockString;

            if (resultString) {
                NSLog(@"The result string is: %@.", resultString);
            }
        }];

        // Output for this call should be: Error: This is an error.
        [testObject testMethod:@"Error string" withCompletionBlock:^(NSString *blockString, NSError __autoreleasing *error) {
            resultString = blockString;

            if (!resultString) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Error not recognized!");
                }
            }
        }];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your TestClass object is released as soon as the main() function exits. Being mainly async, the testMethod: does not block the pointer in the main().

Try adding a semaphore at the end of the main(). This semaphore should be signaled in the testMethod `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` block.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example with a semaphore, as suggested in @CharlesThierry's answer.
I have also included some NSLogs that help illustrate the execution flow:

*TestClass.h*

```
#ifndef TestClass_h
#define TestClass_h

@interface TestClass : NSObject {
}

- (void)testMethod:(NSString *)testString withSemaphore:(dispatch_semaphore_t)sem withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString *blockResult, NSError __autoreleasing *error))completionBlock;

@end

#endif
```

*TestClass.m*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass

- (void)testMethod:(NSString *)testString withSemaphore:(dispatch_semaphore_t)sem withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString *blockResult, NSError __autoreleasing *error))completionBlock {
    __block NSString *stringResult = nil;

    if (completionBlock) {
        __block NSError *resultError = nil;

        NSLog(@"INSIDE TEST METHOD, OUTSIDE DISPATCH ASYNC");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSLog(@"INSIDE THE DISPATCH ASYNC TO THE GLOBAL QUEUE");

            if ([testString isEqual: @"Error string"]) {
                NSDictionary *errorUserInfo = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"This is an error.", NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: @"", NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: @"" };
                resultError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"com.test.TestErrorDomain" code:10 userInfo:errorUserInfo];
            }
            else {
                stringResult = testString;
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"INSIDE THE DISPATCH ASYNC TO THE MAIN QUEUE!");
                completionBlock(stringResult, resultError);
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
            });
        });
    }
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"BEFORE BLOCK");

        __block NSString *resultString = nil;
        TestClass * testObject = [[TestClass alloc] init];
        dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        [testObject testMethod:@"Test string" withSemaphore:sem withCompletionBlock:^(NSString *blockString, NSError __autoreleasing *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"INSIDE FIRST BLOCK");

             resultString = blockString;

             if (resultString)
             {
                 NSLog(@"The result string is: %@.", resultString);
             }
         }];

        [testObject testMethod:@"Error string" withSemaphore:sem withCompletionBlock:^(NSString *blockString, NSError __autoreleasing *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"INSIDE SECOND BLOCK");

             resultString = blockString;

             if (!resultString)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error not recognized!");
                 }
             }
         }];

        NSLog(@"AFTER BLOCK!");

        while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
    }

    return 0;
}
```